# Cannot disable multicast in linux

Tags: linux, multicast

Environment: Two servers connected through a router, both running Ubuntu 16.04

I use the following commands to disable multicast:

```
ifconfig eno1 -multicast
```

or

```
ip link set eno1 multicast off
```

And check the result, no multicast flag:

```
$ ifconfig eno1
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:ca:b8:4b:5b:88  
          inet addr:192.168.1.240  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::34c4:560f:208a:9249/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39493 (39.4 KB)  TX bytes:602751 (602.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000
```

Then I use iperf to test multicast,
One server sends packages:

```
$ iperf -c 226.94.1.1 -u -i 1
```

Another server still receives packages:

```
$ iperf -s -u -B 226.94.1.1 -i 1

------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Binding to local address 226.94.1.1
Joining multicast group  226.94.1.1
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 226.94.1.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.240 port 36855
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec   0.002 ms    0/   89 (0%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec   0.002 ms    0/   89 (0%)
```

It seems multicast mode not disabled.
I don't know why.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you check the state of the interface while iperf is running, does it still show multicast disabled?

Comment: Yes, multicast flag not showed from the result of "ifconfig" when running iperf.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing multicast manually from the avahi-daemon config:

Edit `/etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf`

Replace the line `start on (filesystem and started dbus)` with `start on (never and filesystem and started dbus)`

Then replace the `stop` line with `stop on stopping dbus`

If the `stop` line doesn't exist, just add `stop on stopping dbus` below the `start on` line

You can try restarting networking after for the changes to take effect, or just do a reboot which should do the trick.

Comment: I changed the `/etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf` and reboot, but multicast still works.